# How to wget/curl a dynamically built zip archive?

Tags: bash, curl, wget

I'm trying to create a script that will download a [dynamically built](https://github.com/verekia/initializr) [Initializr](http://initializr.com) zip archive.  Something like:

```
wget http://www.initializr.com/builder?mode=less&boot-hero&h5bp-htaccess&h5bp-nginx&h5bp-webconfig&h5bp-chromeframe&h5bp-analytics&h5bp-build&h5bp-iecond&h5bp-favicon&h5bp-appletouchicons&h5bp-scripts&h5bp-robots&h5bp-humans&h5bp-404&h5bp-adobecrossdomain&jquery&modernizrrespond&boot-css&boot-scripts
```

That url [works in a browser](http://www.initializr.com/builder?mode=less&boot-hero&h5bp-htaccess&h5bp-nginx&h5bp-webconfig&h5bp-chromeframe&h5bp-analytics&h5bp-build&h5bp-iecond&h5bp-favicon&h5bp-appletouchicons&h5bp-scripts&h5bp-robots&h5bp-humans&h5bp-404&h5bp-adobecrossdomain&jquery&modernizrrespond&boot-css&boot-scripts), but not in a script.  In a script it downloads a small portion of the archive, and saves it as `builder?mode=less` instead of `initializr-less-verekia-3.0.zip`.

`builder?mode=less` actually unzips, so it is just a misnamed a zip file.  But it's missing probably 80% of the files it should have.

Anyone know how to script this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

urls contain shell metacharacters, so you'll have to quote the whole url:

```
wget 'your...url...here'
```

If the initializr website doesn't put a proper filename into the HTTP response headers, wget will use a best-guess version based on the url being requested. You can force it to write to a specific filename with

```
wget 'your url here' -O name_of_file.zip
```